# How to enable Command Line Editing in Python interactive mode?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cygwin, readline, interactive

I noticed that on my two Python 3 installations (v3.7 and v3.9), running from Cygwin bash, the command line editing feature (like history with up-arrow) is not working. On Win 10 CMD console it works as expected.

The Python docs explain how to check if the feature is enabled, but not how to activate it.

How can I activate Command Line Editing in the interactive mode?

UPDATE: The Python 3.7 installation is on another computer, and it seems that it is working properly. I do have the Cygwin python (2.7) installed there, but I am using the standalone installation.

Comment: does work using the cygwin version of python ? (3.8.8 is the last one)

Comment: I don't have it installed, so I don't know. If it were, what could we learn from that?